# If change is DV and Pretest is covariate, should random effects take the form of (1|subjects) or (Pretest|subjects)?

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model, ancova, multinomial-logit

I have ***Change*** from Pretest to Posttest (gain, no_gain, decline) as the DV.

***Pretest*** and ***Group*** as covariates. This called for a multinomial regression

```
mod0 <- brm(Change ~ Pretest + Group)
```

**Question:**

I'd like to add random effects of ***Subject*** and ***Word***, but I don't have effect of ***Time*** to do:

```
mod1 <- brm(Change ~ Pretest + Group + (Time|Subject) + (Time|Word))
```

I thought of:

```
mod2 <- brm(Change ~ Pretest + Group + (1|Subject) + (1|Word))
```

and

```
mod3 <- brm(Change ~ Pretest + Group + (Pretest|Subject) + (Pretest|Word))
```

but these also seem wrong to me.

What do you think should be the best form?

Comment: Depends. Do you think the effect of pretest should vary between subjects?

Comment: I think the subjects effect should vary between subjects from pretest to posttest. But since I calculated change, I don't have Time effect to set it in the level for random effects. I do not know what's the alternative in this case.

Comment: How many post-test measurements do you have per subject? If only one, you won't be able to use mixed effects modelling to analyse your data!

Comment: For this analysis, there is a pre-test and only one post-test.  I chose to analyse Change. There would be a difference in participants from pretest to posttest,so could you please explain why I can't use random effects here :( ?

Comment: Sorry, by post-test measurements I thought you meant delayed posttests, my mistake! Yes, for this posttest, every participant was tested on 28 words, so I have 28 rows per subject, if that's what you asked?